# 'twitter-typeahead' gem syntax errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I'm trying to add the `twitter-typeahead` gem to my application, and I'm following this tutorial: http://blog.sed.hu/2014/07/11/ruby-on-rails-search-autocomplete-with-sunspot-solr-and-twitter-typeahead-js-part-2/. I'm getting a few different errors. Does anyone who has used Typeahead see anything glaringly wrong with the tutorial? Or am I doing something wrong?

---

**HERE'S WHAT I DID:**

---

**application.html.erb**

```
<div id="search-wrapper">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

**app/assets/javascripts/search.js.coffee**

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', -&gt;
  users = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
      url: '/users/index?q=%QUERY'
    }
  })

  users.initialize()

  $('input.typeahead').typeahead(
    {
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'things',
      displayKey: 'title',
      source: User.all
  })
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @user = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        results = @user.results.map do |user|
          { title: user.name }
        end
        render json: results
      end
  else
    @user = User.order("created_at DESC")
  end
 end
```

---

**THE ERRORS:**

---

Both errors point to this line in my head:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

and if I remove it, the errors go away, but that's obviously not a preferable solution.

**First Error:**

```
SyntaxError: [stdin]: unexpected &
  (in home/website/app/assets/javascripts/search.js.coffee)
```

Then, if I remove the "&" from "->" on the first line of search.js.coffee, I get this error:

**Second Error:**

```
SyntaxError: [stdin]:2:1: unexpected indentation
  (in home/website/app/assets/javascripts/search.js.coffee)
```

I played around with some of the indentation, but this error I couldn't get to go away.

---

**UPDATE:** I changed my search.js.coffee code as per suggested by NickM, but now I'm getting a different error.

---

**Updated search.js.coffee**

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load',
  users = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
      url: '/users/index?q=%QUERY'
    }
  })

  users.initialize()

  $('input.typeahead').typeahead(
    {
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'things',
    displayKey: 'title',
    source: User.all
    }
  )
```

**New Error**

```
SyntaxError: [stdin]:6:11: unexpected (
  (in /home/website/app/assets/javascripts/search.js.coffee)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try pasting this into your Coffeescript file. Looks like there were a couple of funny characters in there and an unmatched outdent:

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  users = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
      url: '/users/index?q=%QUERY'
    }
  })

  users.initialize()

  $('input.typeahead').typeahead(
    {
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'things',
    displayKey: 'title',
    source: User.all
    }
  )
```

Also, you might find the js2coffee tool useful, which can be found [here](http://js2coffee.org/).

If you paste the contents of your Coffeescript file in the right pane, it will show you if you have syntax errors, or if funny characters are popping up. I use this all the time. Hope it helps.

Comment: Now I'm getting a different, "unexpected (" error message. I updated my question.

Comment: You might need to add -> after the comma on the first line to make it a function. If that doesn't take care of it, I'd look at the text editor you're using. It might be translating spaces or tabs incorrectly and causing the indentation error. See my edit about js2coffee.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of other great tutorials out there. Maybe you would have more luck with some of these:

http://www.arungudelli.com/jquery/simple-jquery-autocomplete-search-tutorial/
http://blattchat.com/2013/01/09/bootstrap-typeahead/
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-typeahead.php
https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/
http://www.bootply.com/86571

A Google search will produce even more.